# How to distinguish between 0 and unset in XText/EMF

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf

Using XText 2.6.2, I have a grammar that references ecore, and a model containing:

```
NumberLiteral :
    int= LONG;

terminal LONG returns ecore::ELong:
    ('-')? (NUMBER)+;

terminal fragment NUMBER:
    '0'..'9';
```

This generates a class NumberLiteralImpl with:

```
  protected static final long INT_EDEFAULT = 0L;
```

and

```
  @Override
  public boolean eIsSet(int featureID)
  {
    switch (featureID)
    {
      case XCoGPackage.NUMBER_LITERAL__INT:
        return int_ != INT_EDEFAULT;
    }
    return super.eIsSet(featureID);
  }
```

which obviously means that when you set the `int` attribute to 0, it counts as unset.

Which is not at all useful; for example, you can't serialise any expression with a 0 in it. If you try, you get an error of the form:

```
org.eclipse.xtext.validation.IConcreteSyntaxValidator$InvalidConcreteSyntaxException: These errors need to be fixed before the model can be serialized.
SystemModel.{*snip*}.value->NumberLiteral: Feature NumberLiteral.int must be set.
```

Is there a fix, or a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent anyone hitting the same issue and finding an unanswered question, the solution I went with as to replace ecore::ELong with ecore::EBigDecimal. As that's an object, it would use a null reference rather that 0 for 'unset'.